# Fill file ASCII values

Tags: c, file-io, aio

I want to create a file filled with 0 or other letters. Here's my function

```
int fill(const int d, struct aiocb *aiorp, void *buf, const int count){
        int rv = 0;
        memset( (void *)aiorp, 0, sizeof( struct aiocb ) ); // <-here second paramether is 0
        aiorp->aio_fildes = d;
        aiorp->aio_buf = buf;
        aiorp->aio_nbytes = count;
        aiorp->aio_offset = 0;
        rv = aio_write( aiorp );
        return rv;
}
```

Here's my main

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
        int des;
        int rv;
        struct aiocb aior;
        char buffer[1000];
        if(argc == 3){
                printf("just %s\n", argv[1]);
                des = createFile(argv[1]);
                rv = fill(des, &aior, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

So my output should be file filled with zero values, but my fle is filled with garbage

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@$
y▒^X^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
s|▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒r|▒^@^@^@^@▒▒^?▒(▒▒▒▒▒{▒▒
y▒^P^@^@^@▒
y▒^A^@^@^@d^Cy▒^@^@^@^@▒
y▒^T
y▒^P▒▒▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
...
```

Why? What's wrong?

Here's the code :

sukurti - create new file if that file don't exist and
fill - fill created file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <aio.h>
#define MB 1024

int sukurti(char *name);
int fill(const int d, struct aiocb *aiorp, void *buf, const int count);

int sukurti(char *name){
   int dskr;
   dskr = open( name, O_RDONLY );
   if( dskr == -1 ){
          printf("Failas sukurtas, nes jo nebuvo\n");
          dskr = open( name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);

   }else{
           printf("Jau yra toks failas!\n");
           exit(1);
   }
   return dskr;
}

int fill(const int d, struct aiocb *aiorp, void *buf, const int count){
        int rv = 0;
        memset( (void *)aiorp, 'A', sizeof( struct aiocb ) );
        aiorp->aio_fildes = d;
        aiorp->aio_buf = buf;
        aiorp->aio_nbytes = count;
        aiorp->aio_offset = 0;
        rv = aio_write( aiorp );
        return rv;

}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
        int des;
        int rv;
        struct aiocb aior;
        int x = atoi(argv[2]);
        printf("%d\n", x);
        int size = MB * MB * x;
        char buffer[size];
        if(argc == 3){
                printf("just %s\n", argv[1]);
                des = sukurti(argv[1]);
                rv = fill(des, &aior, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        }else{
                printf("Blogas\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
I know that my writting to file ends

Comment: Maybe, you shall clear the `buffer` before writing it.

Comment: what/where is your _output_ function?

Comment: `^@` *is* `0`, so no worries where we see that. You're setting `aio_fildes` to an uninitialized integer value, so that'll show up as garbage in the file. Not sure what your output function looks like, but you're pointing `aio_buf` to an uninitialized `buffer`, so that should also be full of garbage (or, if you're just printing the pointer value, it still won't be `0`).  `aio_nbytes` certainly won't be `0`, either. Please show the output function; as it is, nothing here is surprising.

Comment: Just as a simple note, put your code here and don't let it on other sites, so if in a year someone watches this link he can get full data available

Comment: What is the value you type in for `x`/`argv[2]`? How do you call this program? Can you post the exact command line? I strongly suspect your command line is misformed somehow, then atoi can't convert the value to something that makes sense. You really need to add more sanity checks of the command line arguments and defensive programming.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you (try to) use `aio_write()` and not just simply `write()`?

Comment: Well, yes I need to use aio_write()

Comment: Besides you are not initialising the buffer to be written, `main()` propably ends before the asynchronous write completed. To avoid this make sure to setup a notification on when the write completed and do not leave `main()` until this notification was received. See the member `aio_sigevent` of `struct aiocb` for this. Also see `man aio` and `man sigevent` for details.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: It's the call to `aio_write()`.

Answer (score 5):

Three ssues here:

1. `buffer` is not initalised. Do this using

   ```
   memset(buffer, 
     <what ever 8bit value you want the file to be filled with>, 
     sizeof buffer);
   ```

   right after defining it in `main()`.
2. `aior` is initialise wrongly. Initialise it to all `0` using

   ```
   memset(aiorb, 0, sizeof aior);
   ```

   right after defining it in `main()` and remove the call to `memset()` in `fill()`.
3. Finally the program most likely ends **before** the buffer had been asynchronously written to disk.

   To fix this define a notification method as mentioned under [`man 7 aio`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html). And make the program wait for this notification to be received **before** ending the program.

   This for example can be done by asking for completion notification via signal and wait for this signal.

   To do so modify your code as follows:

   - Add the following two lines to the intialisation of what `aiorp` is pointing to in `fill()`:

     ```
     aiorp->aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
     aiorp->aio_sigevent.sigev_signo = SIGUSR1;
     ```
   - To be able to handle the notifying signal sent (without ending the program) a signal handler needs to be setup:

     ```
     void handler(int sig)
     {
       /* Do nothing. */
     }
     ```
   - Install this handler by calling

     ```
     signal(handler, SIGUSR1);
     ```

     right at the beginning of the program.
   - Before `return`ing from `main()` call `wait_for_completion(SIGUSR1)` which might look like this:

     ```
     void wait_for_completion(int sig)
     {
       sigset_t set;
       sigemptyset(&set);
       sigaddset(&set, sig);

       sigwait(&set, &sig); /* This blocks until sig had 
                               been received by the program. */
       printf("Completion notification for asynchronous 'write'-operation received.\n");
     }
     ```

   <sup>*Add error handling as appropriate. I left it out for the sake of readability.*</sup>

Comment: This is the right answer, even catching that the program exits before completing the write.

Answer (score 4):

```
  memset( (void *)aiorp, '0', sizeof( struct aiocb ) );
```

`0` is not `'0'`, you need to actually use the ASCII value (48 if i recall correctly.)

Comment: Well, isnt that what you want ? A file filled with the caracter 0 ? @David

Comment: Well, if I want to have a file filled with 'A' characters?

Comment: then you just write  memset( (void *)aiorp, 'A', sizeof( struct aiocb ) ); and it works !

Comment: from man aio: `The aiocb ("asynchronous I/O control block") structure defines parameters that control an I/O operation.` So, don't fill it with garbage. What must be filled is the buffer.

Comment: I posted my full code. When I write memset( (void *)aiorp, 'A', sizeof( struct aiocb ) ); I still get file with 0 size.

Comment: @David OK, i think i know what's wrong ! Can you change your memset to memset( buf, 'A', sizeof( buf) ); ? And then tell me if that was ok. If it worked i'll edit my answer and tell you why you got that error.

Comment: sorry. still file with 0 size.

Comment: @David Are you sure ? I don't see why you're not getting something different

Comment: Well I changed to memset( buf, 'A', sizeof( buf) ); in my fill method, but I get same results :/

Comment: @David just a quick thing, are you forced to use aio_write ? And where is your close ? Are you sure to check the same file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76464/discussion-between-david-and-mekap).

Comment: This is not the only cause, why the output file stays empty.